# fail2ban logging only mode before banning ip's

Tags: fail2ban

I would like to implement fail2ban on critical production systems and wondering if there is a 'monitoring' mode possible where ip's are not banned but logged to review fail2ban operation first to prevent outages because of config failures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an action [dummy](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.10/config/action.d/dummy.conf) that can be used for this purposes.

So configure it like this in your jail.local for `[jail]` you want test or `[DEFAULT]` section for all jails:

```
[jail]
banaction = dummy[target=/some/path/to/fail2ban.dummy.txt]
```

This works for v.0.10 and higher.
If you have still v.0.9, use `action` instead `banaction` (with all expected parameters) or `banaction = dummy` without `[target=...]` (it would use default target path `/var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.dummy`).